# Define SSRS report's DataSet and DataSource dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm, reporting-services

I'm building an MVVM Light WPF app using Visual Studio 2015 and Entity Framework 6. It needs to have some SSRS *local* reports running inside a `Reports.xaml` view (user control) using the `WindowsFormsHost` control:

```
<WindowsFormsHost x:Name="WindowsFormsHost">
    <rv:ReportViewer x:Name="ReportViewer" />
</WindowsFormsHost>
```

Following the instructions in [this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273267.aspx), I've created a report with an embedded data source and dataset. However, now the app needs to have a `ComboBox` of report names to let the user choose which report to show in the `ReportViewer` control.

Here's what I'd like to do:

1. Have a bunch of RDLC report files, each with the appropriate column names and layout information
2. Be able to switch the dataset in code to call a different stored procedure via Entity Framework

I've tried manually removing the entire `DataSources` and `DataSets` tags from the RDLC file, but that blows it up and Visual Studio comes back with invalid XML errors.

Is it possible to have a report without the dataset/datasource embedded in the XML? Then the RDLC XML would provide the layout and the data would come from the code-behind?

Here's what I've tried in my `Reports.xaml.cs` code-behind from the MSDN article, but it uses embedded dataset and datasource:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "RunReport", RunReport);
}

private void RunReport(string reportName)
{
    Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource reportDataSource1 = 
       new Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource();
    AdventureWorks2008R2DataSet dataset = new AdventureWorks2008R2DataSet();

    dataset.BeginInit();

    //Name of the report dataset in our .RDLC file
    reportDataSource1.Name = "DataSet1"; 
    reportDataSource1.Value = dataset.SalesOrderDetail;
    this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource1);
    this._reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = 
        "<VSProjectName>.Report1.rdlc";

    dataset.EndInit();

    //fill data into adventureWorksDataSet
    AdventureWorks2008R2DataSetTableAdapters.SalesOrderDetailTableAdapter salesOrderDetailTableAdapter = 
       new AdventureWorks2008R2DataSetTableAdapters.SalesOrderDetailTableAdapter();
    salesOrderDetailTableAdapter.ClearBeforeFill = true;
    salesOrderDetailTableAdapter.Fill(dataset.SalesOrderDetail);

    _reportViewer.RefreshReport();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that a better approach to this would be to let the report decide what stored procedure to run based on the parameter value(s) that you pass. Let the report do what a report is meant to do, get and display data. The code behind handles what report to run and when.

The approach you describe smells like a good way to complicate the hell out reporting. Keep it simple, for your sake, and the sake of the person who has to manage the reports after you.